# What is the practical use of list.clear() method in Python?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a reason behind clearing all the values in a list and reusing it, as opposed to deleting the list and creating a new one. Are there any practical advantages of using `clear()` method, aside from situations where the list is referenced in multiple locations, and deleting it might lead to unintended consequences?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by deleting a list? for example, if you go on another iteration in the loop, however you want cleared list and not with some random items from previous iteration. my answer is more useless, because you can use some other language features to achieve exactly same result. interesting discussion about list.clear() method can be found here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401933/why-is-there-no-list-clear-method-in-python , notice that question was asked when list.clear() method wasn't added in python and updated discussion followed after it was added. https://bugs.python.org/issue10516  _ I think this will also be useful.

Comment: Deleting a list means if I really need to do list.clear() and use it again, I can use empty list and I can delete my list if memory or other resource optimizations are required